# EMFILE: Too many files open

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, bottle

I'm trying to set up an api on azure's web app service using bottle + anaconda packages.

I can't simply use a copy of the site-packages folder because numpy is involved. Instead, in addition to the site-packages folder I must also give numpy access to the mkl binaries. So I copy the `Anaconda\envs\{ENV_NAME}\Library\bin` folder into the app and add it to %PATH%. That folder has less than 200 files in it, so I'm surprised seeing the following error during the deployment:

```
 2020-10-29T04:34:21.3218237Z ##[error]Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'D:\a\_temp\temp_web_package_058969368946595324\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima\datasets\__init__.py'
```

Everything builds and runs as long as I don't include the bin folder to %PATH%

No, I'm not close to my file size limit on the azure web app service. Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because of the XDT Transform.

During an XDT Transform, all contents of the original package are transformed and then zipped up. This error is thrown if the deployment is significantly large.